# SignalR Join Group new Context.ConnectionId on browser refresh

Tags: signalr

My app has a bunch of UserGroups.

There is an Admin page which can send out Notifications to 1 or many of these usergroups.

I have a Hub which the Admin can post the notifications to after they are saved to the database via a AJAX call to a WebAPI method.  When this returns in the Ajax success section I then call a method on the server hub which posts the notification realtime to 1 or more groups.  The groups are indicated by an array of int which creates group names by just converting the int with .ToString().

The clients have a widget on their home page which shows the notifications.  Some of the users can be part of more than 1 userGroup, but they have a dropdownlist at the top of the page which specifies which UserGroupd they are currently viewing.  Thus they may be part of many UserGroups but only view 1 at a time.

Thus I am doing like Jabbr Chatrooms I guess, but I don't want to set it up quite so much because the app has a different intention.  So when the client logs in they join a group based on the value of the Selected item in the dropdownlist.  I did notice that whenever I refresh the page as a client the 'Join' server method is called again with a new connectionId.  Is this right?  I don't want to have more connections than there actually are.  I will also still need to disconnect the client from the group and rejoin them to a new group when they change the dropdownlist.

I am looking for demos but find either very easy demo or very sophisticated one and I am aiming initially for something in between, since there are other areas of the site I intend to add SignalR functionality to so don't want to lock down my object model too much.

So on my Hub I got:

```
public void Join(string groupName) {
  Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}

public void SendNotificationsToGroups(string title, string description, int[] groups) {
        foreach (int i in groups) {
            Clients.OthersInGroup(i.ToString()).addMessage(Title, description);
        }
}
```

The Admin page calls the SendNotificationsToGroups and this works fine.  As you see it passes an array of ints which are the groups to broadcast the notification to.  I just .ToString the int to create GroupNames.

The client does the following:

```
var Hub = $.connection.myHub;

Hub.client.addMessage = function (title, description) {
  $('#Notification').find('tr:first').before('<tr><td>'+title+description'</td></tr>');
}

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    var groupId = $('#userGroupID').val();
    newsHub.server.join(groupId);
}
```

My main concern again is the join method as the addMessage part works!! Admin sends notifications and clients see them.  Issue is if client refreshes their browser Join is called again on the server (I got a breakpoint set on it) and it has a new Context.ConnectionId.  Is this bad?  Is this causing more connections than necessary.  Is there a javascript/jQuery call that I should make to ensure the connection if destroyed if the window is closed of the client leaves the page, what about the browser refresh issue.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR [hooks the window's unload event and calls `.stop()` on the connection](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.core.js#L410), but it does so with an asynchronous message so it might not happen immediately. Also, the server side will automatically detect and weed out "dead" connections as part of its housekeeping chores.

That said, it would be best to keep the SignalR connection alive if you can rather than disconnecting/reconnecting on every page navigation. Constantly disconnecting and reconnecting kinda defeats the purpose and you could obviously miss some messages between page navigations.

Comment: Care to elaborate on how you'd do that (prevent connectionId recycling between refreshes)? Thanks

Comment: I don't really know the exact context of your application, but one way would be to move to a modern, single page application (SPA) model where the SignalR connection is connected up when the SPA starts and then you can dynamically load in various sections of your app as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was to store the user's session and connectionId in a 1-to-many table with users.  For example, you can create a PersonSession table that stores the above plus additional info such as host, connect time, disconnect time, and user-agent.

You can grab the session on the `OnConnected()`method using the following code:

```
var session = Context.RequestCookies.ContainsKey("ASP.NET_SessionId") ? Context.RequestCookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value : null;
```

and store it along with the connectionId in the db.  In the `OnDisconnected()` method, you just update this record with a DisconnectTiemstamp.

then when they refresh, you can check previous records (I keep up to 3 records for a user at any time), to see if they have the same session, and if they do, then you don't update, otherwise, you assume that this is a new session and do the update.

```
if (session != null)
{
     var MyInActiveSessions = p.PersonSessions.Where(x=>x.DisconnectTimestamp != null);
                            bUpdateStatus = !MyInActiveSessions.Any(x => x.SessionID != null &&          x.SessionID == session);
}
```

Also, bear in mind that you'll have to force the regeneration of the Session cookie on login, because ASP.net keeps the old session cookie even when you logout.  To do this, you'd need to do several things:

1. In your login code, put any random value in the Session variable to force ASP.NET to generate the cookie (e.g. `Session['0'] = 0;`)
2. In your logout code, abandon the session and add the cookie to the response:

   `Session.Abandon();
   Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));`
3. Finally, in Web.config, make sure your session is automatically regenrated:

`<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"></sessionState>`

Hope this helps.